# Tensorflow Extended distributed training on AWS

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, apache-beam, tensorflow-extended

I'm new to Tensorflow extended, I knew TFX uses Apache beam with Runners like Spark, Dataflow to connect to GCP. The question I have is, can I use TFX for distributed training on AWS? Does Apache Beam which is used by TFX has support for AWS clusters?

Thanks